numpy gather along different axis
Maybe theres a better way, but I couldn't find a satisfactory answer online so heres the code i use if someone needs it:
import numpy as np


def np_gather(array: np.ndarray, indices: np.ndarray, axis: tuple, value: np.ndarray = None):
    """
    gather and affect indices behaviour along different non contiguous axis
    """
    assert isinstance(axis, tuple)
    assert len(axis) > 0

    shape_o = array.shape
    axis_o = np.arange(array.ndim)
    permute_shape = axis_o[np.logical_not(np.isin(axis_o, axis))].tolist()
    permute_shape.extend(axis)
    safe_dims = np.array(shape_o)[np.logical_not(np.isin(axis_o, axis))]
    unsafe_dims = np.array(shape_o)[np.isin(axis_o, axis)]

    array = np.transpose(array, permute_shape)
    array = array.reshape((*safe_dims, -1))

    offsets = np.cumprod(np.insert(unsafe_dims, unsafe_dims.shape[0], 1)[1:][::-1])[::-1]
    indices_temp = (indices * offsets.reshape(indices.shape[0], 1)).sum(axis=0)

    if not value is None:
        array[..., indices_temp] = value.reshape(*[1 for d in safe_dims], *value.shape)

    return array[..., indices_temp]

Example :
array1 = np.random.randn(10,10)
check = array1>0
array2 = np.tile(array1.reshape(1,1,10,10),(4,6,1,1)).transpose(0,2,1,3)
nix = np.stack(np.nonzero(check))
print((np_gather(array2,nix,(1,3))>0).all())

new_value = np.ones(nix.shape[-1])*0.12
returned_values = np_gather(array2,nix,(1,3),new_value)
print((returned_values==0.12).all())

Also it's not letting me post the code because there is not enough text, so here is some, blabla

What is your question?

I’m voting to close this question because it's not a question but just a code fragment.
